# How to preload images with an image swap script jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I am using this script at the moment to swap images, because I need to use SVGs and then I use SVGeezy.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }
    $('img.switch').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

and the HTML I use is

```
<img class="switch" data-alt-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/ost-meetthetribe-rollover.svg" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/ost-meetthetribe.svg">
```

There is a delay between the two different images because the browser only loads the rollover image when the user hovers over.

So I found this little script from another answer and came up with this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }
    $('img.switch').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
// Preload:
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
// Usage:
preload([
    'img/ost-whattopack-rollover.svg',
    'img/ost-whattopack-rollover.png',
    'img/ost-whattopack.svg',
    'img/ost-whattopack.png',
    'img/ost-meetthetribe-rollover.svg'
    'img/ost-meetthetribe-rollover.png'
    'img/ost-meetthetribe.svg'
    'img/ost-meetthetribe.png'
]);
```

So this isn't working at all. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    var i = 0;
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        imageelmentObj = new Image();
        images[i] = imageelmentObj.src = this;
        i++;
    });
}
```

Comment: Do I also need to add to add the 
preload([
section?